# Chicken and Egg: Database design

Tags: mysql, database-design, content-management-system, normalization

I have this table, I bet that looking at the tables, you will know my problem already :)

```
content_table
--------------------------------------
| id |   title   | type  | parent_id |
--------------------------------------
| 0  |   Root    | Page  |    0      |
|100 |   Home    | Page  |    1      |
|101 | Main Text |Section|    1      |
|102 |   About   | Page  |    1      |
|301 |    Foo    | Text  |   245     |
|302 | About Us  | Text  |   246     |
--------------------------------------

paging_table
---------------------------------
| page_id | section_id | rel_id |
---------------------------------
|   0     |     0      |    1   |
|  100    |    101     |   245  |
|  102    |    101     |   246  |
---------------------------------

section_options
----------------------------
| section_id | option_mask |
----------------------------
|   101      |   65535     |
----------------------------
*paging_table.page_id and paging_table.section_id 
  both have FOREIGN KEYs on content_table.id

 section_options.section_id has a FOREIGN KEY on content_table.id
```

So basically I have a CMS and I want to treat EVERYTHING as a content, be it a page, a page section, or the actual contents of the pages themselves.

Secondly, since some page sections will be quite similar, I decided that I need not create multiple sections (e.g. *home_main_text*, *about_main_text*, etc...). I just need to create a generic section and have the `paging_table` take care of the rest since sections will also have a whole lot of display options with them (stored in another table that has a reference to `content_table.id`). If I am to have similar sections with very similar options stored in two rows, that would look bad wouldn't it?

Then I created a `root` content (the one with `id = 0` at the `content_table`). All main pages and sections will have the `root` as their parent.

My problem now is that I want to put a `FOREIGN KEY` on `parent_id` that references to the `rel_id` column. But I have the `Root` element to worry about. I already feel like I am doing a hack on the first row of the `paging_table`. I am now feeling a chicken and egg scenario for the root content. Do you think there really is a necessity for the root content? How about the generic section approach? I just want a better design of this database :), or maybe an overall redesign of architecture of the CMS since I'm just starting and I really haven't done much yet.

Criticisms are very much welcome (just be constructive). If there is anything vague, please comment and I will try to clear it up, I just am having a hard time articulating what I have in mind and it would really be a hassle if I simply sent you the source code the classes that I am building. Thanks!

**EDIT**

I've edited the id's to make the references clear

Comment: I don't understand the function of the paging_table, can you explain that more? Your design with sub-typing (Section pointing to a Content record) sounds fine.

Comment: Hi! Well since each section is generic, I have to find a way to 'mix and match' sections and pages. Does that answer it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really see a problem there. I would just leave the parent_id of Root to `Null`: it has no parent, and it is NOT his own parent.
Otherwise, SQL Server (and probably some other RDBMS) has [hierarchical capabilities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc794278.aspx).

Comment: But that would prevent me from adding a foreign key at parent_id that will reference to rel_id, right?

Comment: @Rolando Cruz: I don't think so. A join (self join in this case) can be defined allowing FK values empty

Comment: You can model hierarchies with RDBMS,  but there are better alternatives now.

Comment: MySQL throws an error even when I set the root's parent_id to NULL

Comment: That's the thing to fix...I not an MySql expert. I suggest you add that tag to your question if you're bound to MySql.

Answer (score 0):

Let me be blasphemic:  relational databases are not suitable for this kind of task - building hierarchies with relations clearly sucks.   I also did same mistake once,   and would never do this again.  I created small and lightweight CMS  with just file system as storage, and XML documents.  Other concepts like versioning, replication, workflow  are easy to put on
with (surprise!!!!) -  some source versioning system like git  or svn.

Another option would be document oriented database like MongoDB (there are others, but I'm most familiar with mongo now) - no schema,   easy hiarachies, scales out well  - what else you need? ( and there is PHP driver )

To hell with normalized data ;)

Comment: "blasphemic"?  I think the proper term is "blasphemous".  The rest of your stuff is spot on, even if it's blasphemic.

Comment: I don't agree: please go with normalized data it will save you pain in the functional area.

Comment: Hmmmmmm... I am actually a self taught developer and have very little experience with database management (I just read about the normal forms 2 weeks ago. LOL). But I will look into MongoDB. My concern would be availability since most hosting sites offer only PHP MySQL and I do intend to release it as an open source project (yes, very ambitious of me). I do not want to scare away end users simply because of me using MongoDB over MySQL. But I really will look at MongoDB and weigh the consequences

Comment: @buddhabrot  content is not functional data - usually content is a big mess (structurally) and it just does not fit  intto relational data model. RDBMS is misused as persistent store  here. It offers no  advantages in this context (buit is still used there because there are developer skills, and rdbms systems)

Comment: @RolandoCruz I also self taug myself mongodb in some 2-3 days  - I started pet pro bono project to analyze and visualize minicipal fiscal data  (they are also not well structured)

Answer (score 0):

Your Section points to a Content record now, this is good.
However, you need to get rid of the awkward paging_table:

Each Section may point to a Page and has an integer describing the "order" in that parent relationship.
If a Section does not point to a Page, it points to another Section, you can reuse the "order" field.

So you have parent_page and parent_section fields, one of which may be NULL. If you're crazy about normalizing you'll need more Section tables, but you may need more than you think.

Note that you will lose hierarchic information in your content_table, but this is OK since there is nothing generally hierarchic about all "content". Only sections are hierarchic.

An even simpler way would be to see a Page as just a type of Section that does not have a parent Section. But I don't know enough of the other data that may be involved in pages. In a regular Wiki I would use that, however.

**EDIT**:
If you really need to "reuse" the actual Section records, you need a SectionAssignment table that allows a m-n relationship between Sections and Pages. SectionAssignment will have four fields: assignment_id, section_id, page_id, and order.

Comment: Hi. If I make a section point to a page, then I would have to create another row for a similar section that belongs to another page right? So I'd have duplicated data for two sections whose only difference is that they belong to different pages (i.e. difference in just one column)

Comment: If they belong to a different page, what exactly do they still have in common? Title? That may be changed by anyone in the future, right? Seems like you just want two records.

Comment: If you really need to reuse sections, you need a different table called "SectionAssignment", I will add this in my answer..

Comment: Hi! I've edited the question further to demonstrate the section options. I have a lot more columns within that section_options table. And I really do think that the main text section will be duplicated a lot

Comment: Isn't the SectionAssignment similar in spirit to the paging table? I just can't find the right word for it.